# Does it make sense to return Try[Option[String]]?

Tags: scala

I'm writing a method which has three possible return states:

- The operation can have failed with an exception
- The operation can have succeeded with a String result
- The operation can have succeeded with no results

Does the return type `Try[Option[String]]` seem correct? Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: If that's the granularity you want, then that's the way I'd go. So yes, it makes sense.

Comment: Does it need to be in the standard lib, or are libraries okay?  Because this is one of the reasons I like Lift's [`Box{Full,Empty,Failure}`](http://liftweb.net/api/26/api/index.html#net.liftweb.common.Box) type.  (I'm sure scalaz has something better, I just don't know scalaz very well yet).

Comment: Scalaz has `NonEmptyList[Char]`, you can see some usages here: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/example/src/main/scala/scalaz/example/StringUsage.scala#L8, though you would probably be returning `Try[Option[NonEmptyList[String]]]` which can be a bit much, but at least you don't have to worry about empty strings :)

Comment: Should be `Try[Option[NonEmptyList[Char]]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is perfectly fine. Another approach is to define your own case classes/objects

```
sealed trait Result
case class OperationFailed(e: Exception) extends Result 
case class SuccessValue(str: String) extends Result 
case object SuccessNoValue extends Result
```

Edit:
This approach may work better with pattern matching, specially if you are using Akka.

```
val f: Any => Any = { case x: Try[Option[String]] => x.get.get.toUpperCase }
f(Try(Some("x")))
f(Try(Some(5))) // Throws java.lang.ClassCastException
```

The above would show the following warning

> warning: non-variable type argument Option[String] in type pattern
>   scala.util.Try[Option[String]] is unchecked since it is eliminated by
>   erasure

Comment: I don't know why you had to add the "your own types" idea; otherwise it'd have been a +1 from me.

Comment: It depends on your taste. For me, it is more readable to have flat types covering all cases, than having multiple type classes nested inside each other.

Comment: multiple type classes? anyway; it's about the methods you get for free with Try and Option.

Comment: Sure they are useful. I am not arguing which style is better, use whatever you feel correct. There is no universally correct answer. 
For me I tend to only use pattern matching on the returned value, so this style is convenient for me.

Comment: 1) `Try(Option(3)) match { case Success(Some(i)) => i; case _ => 0 }` works perfectly well... and 2) [type class](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html) means something very different.

Comment: 1) According to this [Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class#Higher-kinded_polymorphism). Option and Try, who take type parameters and return types are considered type classes.  
 
2) I agree. This is exactly the very first sentence of my answer.

Comment: `Option` and `Try` are not type classes.

Comment: I think we reached a dead end. If you want, you can start a new question to resolve the debate.

Answer (score 2):

Lift's Box does a nice job of combining the semantics of Option and Try

A Box can be:

- Full(value) => Some(value): Option
- Empty       => None: Option
- Failure(ex) => Failure: Try

http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.3/net/liftweb/common/Box.html